# How to make an image appear immediately after being added to firebase without restarting Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

My code is normal, but if I add data to Firebase the image does not appear, but if it has restarted the application appears by itself and the image successfully appears, how to resolve it?

```
child: new Container(
       child: Image.network(
            '${doc.data["image"]}' + '?alt=media',),
             width: 170,
             height: 120,
  ),
```

here's the code to add it

```
void createData() async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String format = DateFormat('dd:mm:yy').format(now);
    var fullImageName = 'foto-$format' + '.jpg';
    var fullImageName2 = 'foto-$format' + '.jpg';

    final StorageReference ref =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fullImageName);
    final StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(image);

    var part1 =
        'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/db-tubes.appspot.com/o/';

    var fullPathImage = part1 + fullImageName2;
    print(fullPathImage);

    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      DocumentReference ref = await db
          .collection('resep')
          .add({'nama': '$nama', 'resep': '$resep', 'image': '$fullPathImage', 'email' : widget.email});
      setState(() => id = ref.documentID);
      Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: You'll need stream for continuous update. You've not written any code related to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StorageUploadTask task` is a Future, so you need to wait upload task to complete to get the URL

try this

```
void createData() async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String format = DateFormat('dd:mm:yy').format(now);
    var fullImageName = 'foto-$format' + '.jpg';
    var fullImageName2 = 'foto-$format' + '.jpg';

    final StorageReference ref =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fullImageName);
    final StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(image);

    // Wait upload task to complete
    final StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl = 
    (await task.onComplete);
    // Get image uRL
    final String url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());


    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      DocumentReference ref = await db
          .collection('resep')
          .add({'nama': '$nama', 'resep': '$resep', 'image': '$url', 'email' : widget.email});
      setState(() => id = ref.documentID);
      Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: fine sir i will try first

Comment: can i get your email, i'm having a hard time about flutter can you help

Answer (score 0):

This is just a demonstration for your idea.

```
Future uploadFile() async {    
   StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance    
       .ref()    
       .child('chats/${Path.basename(_image.path)}}');    
   StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);    
   await uploadTask.onComplete;    
   print('File Uploaded');    
   storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {    
     setState(() {    
       _uploadedFileURL = fileURL;    
     });    
   });    
 }
```

In the setState put that URL into local variable and use that local variable to your image file as network and it will automatically fetch on the next Dom creation.

Answer (score 0):

If the image doesn't update when refreshing the widget, I see a common issue here with writing files to the same address/name in firebase storage.
Somehow image widgets don't understand that the image has been updated if the file name is the same as the old file name like: "2019-11-19-file.jpg". If you write to that again, it won't update.

In that case, you should make the filename have a random component to it, like a UTC milliseconds timestamp name ("1234512312-file.jpg"), or add "&random=[insert random number here]" to the end of your image URL string.

Comment: did it fix your problem?